# MOSFET - what is ohmic region in transconductance curve?

Tags: mosfet

For mosfet transconductance curve, I'm used to seeing ohmic/linear region in output charactersitics(drain curves), and for the transconductance a regular parabola going on forever.

But recently I encountered below curve  which is flattening after some \$V_{GS}\$ and the author was calling it ohmic region. Does this mean the drain current doesn't increase even if we increase \$V_{GS}\$? Really appreciate if someone please explain why this happens...
[image]

Figure 12-9b shows a typical transconductance curve. There is no drain
current until VGS = VGS(th). The drain current then increases rapidly until it reaches
the saturation current ID(sat). ***Beyond this point, the device is biased in the ohmic
region. Therefore, ID cannot increase, even though VGS increases.*** To ensure hard saturation,
a gate voltage of VGS(on) well above VGS(th) is used, as shown in Fig. 12-9b.

Comment: Ohmic means Id proportional to Vds, or Id = Vds/Rds(on). Note the (lack of) dependence on Vgs in this expression.

Comment: @user_1818839 ty I maybe wrong but the transconductance curve is plotted for a fixed value of *Vds = Vgs-Vth*, right? Also I have never seen a transconductance curve flattening like this... Googling gives a simple parabola starting from \$V_{GS} = V_{th}\$ to \$V_{GS} = \infty\$

Comment: Can you cite the source from which this graph was taken?

Comment: No, the RH graph shows fixed Vds but its value is nothing to do with Vgs or Vth. Note the X axis is Vgs not Vds. The OHMIC region (flat, I independent of Vgs) corresponds to the gradient region on the LH graph (Id proportional to Vds)